# How to make this Layout In ASP.NET Page?

Tags: asp.net

I Want To Make This Layout in ASP.Net Page And Want Every Circle Of Those is an ImageButton and when hover on the ImageButton it Shows A text In a `<div></div>` tag in the middle of the circles.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<style >
.modalBackground 
{
    background-color:Gray;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7;
}
.modalPopup
{
    background-color:#ffffdd;
    border-width:3px; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:Gray; 
    padding:3px; 
    width:200px; 
}
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Welcome To SeearaBook 
</h2>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<a id="SeearaBook" runat="server" href="#">سيرة بووك</a>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" Width="525px" BorderStyle="Solid"
BorderColor="#333737" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="3px" Height="170px" >
<cc1:hovermenuextender ID="HoverMenuExtender1" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="A" PopupControlID="Ages" PopupPosition="Left" HoverDelay="200">
</cc1:hovermenuextender>
<div id ="Ages" style="position: fixed; display: none; color:Blue; font-size:20px; background-color:transparent; width:auto;" >
سيتم دخولك الى عالم سيرة باختيارك للزمان
</div>
<cc1:hovermenuextender ID="HoverMenuExtender2" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="P" PopupControlID="Places" PopupPosition="Left" HoverDelay="200">
</cc1:hovermenuextender>
<div id ="Places" style="position: fixed; display: none; color:Blue; font-size:20px; background-color:transparent; width:auto;" >
سيتم دخولك الى عالم سيرة باختيارك للمكان
</div>
<cc1:hovermenuextender ID="HoverMenuExtender3" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="C" PopupControlID="Char" PopupPosition="Left" HoverDelay="200">
</cc1:hovermenuextender>
<div id ="Char" style="position: relative; display: none; color:Blue; font-size:20px; background-color:transparent; width:auto;" >
مازال العمل جاري عليها
</div>
<cc1:hovermenuextender ID="HoverMenuExtender4" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="E" PopupControlID="Events" PopupPosition="Left" HoverDelay="200">
</cc1:hovermenuextender>
<div id ="Events" style="position: relative; display: none; color:Blue; font-size:20px; background-color:transparent; width:auto;" >
مازال العمل جاري عليها
</div>
<cc1:hovermenuextender ID="HoverMenuExtender5" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="N" PopupControlID="Not" PopupPosition="Left" HoverDelay="200">
</cc1:hovermenuextender>
<div id ="Not" style="position: relative; display: none; color:Blue; font-size:20px; background-color:transparent; width:auto;" >
مازال العمل جاري عليها
</div>
<div align="right">
<asp:ImageButton ID="A" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" Height="50px" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/Ages.jpg" onclick="A_Click" Width="50px"  />
<br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="P" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" Height="50px" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/Places.jpg" onclick="P_Click" Width="50px" />
<br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="C" BorderWidth="2px" runat="server" Height="50px" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/Characters.jpg" Width="50px" onclick="C_Click" />
<br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="E" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" Height="50px" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/Events.jpg" Width="50px" onclick="E_Click" />
<br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="N" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" Height="50px" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/5.jpg" Width="50px" onclick="N_Click" />
<br />
<div align="center">
<asp:Button ID="btnCancelpopup" runat="server" Text="Cancel" BorderStyle="Groove" />
</div>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
<cc1:AnimationExtender id="OpenAnimation" runat="server" TargetControlID="SeearaBook">
<Animations>
    <OnClick>
        <Sequence>
            <EnableAction Enabled="false" />
            <Parallel AnimationTarget="pnlpopup" Duration=".75" Fps="25">
                <Move Horizontal="25" Vertical="-50" />
                <Resize Height="350" Width="475" />
            </Parallel>
        </Sequence>
    </OnClick>
</Animations>
</cc1:AnimationExtender>
<cc1:AnimationExtender id="CloseAnimation" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnCancelpopup">
<Animations>
    <OnClick>
        <Sequence>
            <EnableAction Enabled="true"
                AnimationTarget="SeearaBook" />
            <Parallel AnimationTarget="pnlpopup" Duration=".75" Fps="25">
                <Move Horizontal="0" Vertical="0" />
                <Resize Height="170" Width="525" />
            </Parallel>
        </Sequence>
    </OnClick>
</Animations>
</cc1:AnimationExtender>
<cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="rce" runat="server"
TargetControlID="pnlpopup"
Radius="10"
BorderColor="#333737"
Corners="All" />
<cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" runat="server"
TargetControlID="A"
Radius="25"
BorderColor="#333737"
Corners="All" />
<cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender2" runat="server"
TargetControlID="P"
Radius="25"
BorderColor="#333737"
Corners="All" />
<cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender3" runat="server"
TargetControlID="C"
Radius="25"
BorderColor="#333737"
Corners="All" />
<cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender4" runat="server"
TargetControlID="E"
Radius="25"
BorderColor="#333737"
Corners="All" />
<cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender5" runat="server"
TargetControlID="N"
Radius="25"
BorderColor="#333737"
Corners="All" />
<cc1:DropShadowExtender ID="dse" runat="server"
TargetControlID="pnlpopup" 
Opacity=".8" 
Rounded="true"
TrackPosition="true" />
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="SeearaBook" 
    PopupControlID="pnlpopup"  
    CancelControlID="btnCancelpopup" 
    EnableViewState="true"
    DropShadow="true"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
</asp:Content>`
```

Comment: Please paste your code into a code block in your question rather than linking to downloads. I have removed the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the `ImageMap` control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295596.aspx If you want some `mouseover` effects you might also need javascript. Good luck!

Edit:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


        function changeMiddleText(text) {
            //I don't have time to position this div. Find a way to do it
            //and that's it.
            document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div id="divContent">
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; width: 304px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <img id="divMap" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/slQsk.png" usemap="#map" border="0"
            width="304" height="306" alt="" />
        <map id="map" name="map">
            <area shape="poly" onmouseover="changeMiddleText('Text1');" coords="153, 2, 189, 31, 152, 67, 120, 36"
                href="#" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="poly" onmouseover="changeMiddleText('Text2');" coords="267, 90, 297, 123, 266, 156, 235, 123"
                href="#" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="poly" onmouseover="changeMiddleText('Text3');" coords="221, 231, 252, 263, 222, 295, 190, 264"
                href="#" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="poly" onmouseover="changeMiddleText('Text4');" coords="77, 236, 108, 269, 76, 299, 46, 268"
                href="#" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="poly" onmouseover="changeMiddleText('Text5');" coords="34, 92, 66, 120, 31, 152, 2, 122"
                href="#" alt="" title="" />
            <area shape="circle" id="middleContent" coords="153, 157, 67" alt="" />
        </map>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

[JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/k9YdW/3/)

GL!

Comment: I didn't ask for this , i just want to know how to arrange ImageButtons On My Page Like In The Image, That's it.

Comment: My dear friend. I introduced you to the correct way of doing this, which is either using a ImageMap asp.net control, or using a normal html image map. I will show you with an example in a little bit.

Comment: If you want to have specifically LinkButtons or ImageButtons so that you can have Server trips, you can do it with the ImageMap control, use the same coordinates and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning of the elements. Just make sure to contain the elements within a container, such as a div, that has `position:relative`

Example:

```
<div style="position:relative; height: 400px; width: 500px; background-color: yellow;">
 <img id="topleft" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 100px;">
 <img id="topright" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; right: 100px;">
 <img id="topcenter" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 250px;">
 <img id="bottomleft" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; left: 100px;">
 <img id="bottomright" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; right: 100px;">
 <img id="center" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 200px;">
</div>
```

I used simple HTML tags for example purposes to communicate the concept of absolute positioning. Replace the img tags with your ImageButtons, etc.

You can fiddle around with the top/left/bottom/top css values to place your child elements exactly where you would like.